# Need an explicit formula for a recurrence relation involving modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I have a function $F(t)$ defined as follows:
$$F_{n}(t) = Q(F_{n-1}(t))$$
With the following definitions:
$$F_0(t) = t$$
$$Q(t) = W(t \bmod H) + \frac{t}{H}$$
$W$ and $H$ are constant parameters. $W$, $H$ and $t$ are all integers.

I am having  a difficult time coming up with an explicit definition of $F_n(t)$ that is not recurrent. I am not sure how to deal with the modulo operation in $Q(t)$. I've noticed that $F(t)$ is periodic, with the period being some function of $W$ and $H$ that looks very random.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something is missing: do you mean that $F(t) = \lim_{n\to \infty} F_n(t)$, pointwise?

Comment: No, at some point $F_{n+m}(t) = F_n(t)$ for some value of $m$.